# Configuring two internet connections with Dynamic WAN IP

Tags: networking, internet, routing

I had similar problems with [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517561/configuring-two-internet-connections), the difference is my WAN IP assigned dynamically from the ISPs.

So how do I try the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/517617/393364) with dynamic WAN IP ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517561/configuring-two-internet-connections/517617#517617) because, like you say, your ip addresses is dynamically assigned from ISP.

Also you will have different routing. Only you can do is routing based on interfaces, not based on ip.

Example:

```
sudo route add -host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx dev ZZZ
```

or

```
sudo route add -net yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/qq dev ZZZ
```

`ZZZ` represent network card, aka `eth0` or `eth1`

Comment: I did `sudo route add -net 192.168.8.0/24 dev eth3` (eth3 is ISP). But the internet connection in my network (not the ISP) becomes down. Perhaps because I have had `192.168.8.0 - 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.0 - eth2` (eth2 - 192.168.8.1) in IP routing table